# Redirect Loop In Rails App - NoNonsense Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am going through the second tutorial in the No Nonsense Guide To Rails and after setting up user authentication (manually without Devise), I keep getting a redirect loop error once I had successfully logged in and out (started after hitting log out). Now I can't get any page on LocalHost to load anymore. Here is the Application Controller, Sessions Controller, and my routes.rb code:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :comments

  resources :image_posts

  resources :text_posts

  resources :posts

  resources :users

  get 'signup', to: 'users#new', as: 'signup'

  get 'login', to: 'sessions#new', as: 'login'
  post 'login', to: 'sessions#create'
  get 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'logout'

  root 'posts#index'
```

sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    def new
    end

    def create
        user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
        if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
            session[:user_id] = user.id
            redirect_to root_url, notice: "Log in Successful!"
        else
            flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
            render "new"
        end
    end

    def destroy
        session[:user_id] = nil
        redirect_to root_url, notice: "Log out successful!"
    end
end
```

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_action :authenticate_user!
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  private

  def current_user
    if session[:user_id]
        @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
    end
  end

  helper_method :current_user

  def authenticate_user!
    redirect_to login_path unless current_user
  end
```

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you auth user even on `login_path` page... 
Try

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!
  #...
end
```

Comment: That helped! I just needed to remove the before_action :authenticate_user! from the application controller and confirm it was in the posts controller - now it is working again! Appreciate it!